# XamarinUITest How to get text from alert pop up in android App

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest, uitest

Our application is built on xamarin form and I am performing xamarin UITest to automate the android native app.

Problem:
During the validation I have to get the text from pop up box to compare with expected text

My approach:
Using app.repl() I have identified the AppQuery of buttons in pop up and able to perform action on them(PFB Screenshot).
But i am not ale to get the text of pop up message. Tried to use uiautomator to get identify the pop up elements but couldn't identify the xpath

Expected Output: Please confirm that the following S-Number is correct: S855555

can someone please guide me on how to get the pop up text and validate in xamarin uitest.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRddT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9so3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, below query is able to return the text from the screenshot

app.Query(x => x.Id("scrollView").Descendant().Id("message").Id("message").Invoke("getText"))[0];

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9so3.png

Answer (score 0):

You could try the code below:

```
app.Query(c=>c.Marked("Confirm").Parent().Class("AlertDialogLayout"))
```

For more details, you could refer to the link below.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ad1079f7-0406-4709-86ae-7945f93b79e5/handling-popups-with-xamarinuitest?forum=xamarintestcloud

Answer (score 0):

app.Query(e => e.Id("message"))[0].Text

app.Query(e => e.Id("message")).First().Text

AppResult[] resultsArray = app.Query(e => e.Id("message"))

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.uitest.queries.appquery.text?view=xamarin-uitest-sdk

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).